# Lagging issue in collaborative drawing app (React and socketio)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, mern, web-development-server

I am trying to make a collaborative drawing app using react and socketio which helps in real-time drawing. When there is a single user the canvas is working smoothly without any lag but whenever any other user joins and draws anything on the canvas, the drawing gets laggy on other user's screen

I am continuously sending the location of my cursor to other users to track and draw on other users' screen. I don't know what is causing the lag.

Here is my frontend code for any user interaction using mouse

```
const handleMouseEvent = (e) => {
var x, y
if(e.type === 'touchmove'){
  x = e.touches[0].clientX;
  y = e.touches[0].clientY;
}else{
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
}
if(mouseDown){
  socket.emit('mouse:draw', {code, x, y, color})
  ctx.lineTo(x, y)
  ctx.strokeStyle = color
  ctx.stroke()
}
if(socket) socket.emit("mouse:move", {code, x, y, memberName: location.state.username})
```

};

Here is the code to draw on canvas when other users draw something

```
socket.on("mouse:ondraw", (data)=>{
  ctx.lineTo(data.x, data.y)
  console.log(data.color)
  ctx.strokeStyle = data.color
  ctx.stroke()
})

socket.on("mouse:onDown", (data)=>{
  ctx.moveTo(data.x, data.y)
  ctx.beginPath()
})
```

Here is the server side code for the event "mouse:draw"

```
module.exports = (io)=>{

const MouseDraw = function(data){
    const socket = this
    const code = data.code
    const x = data.x
    const y = data.y
    const color = data.color
    socket.to(code).emit("mouse:ondraw", {x, y, color})
}
return{
    MouseDraw
}
```

}

Comment: You may be sending too many messages if you are continuously sending the cursor position. Try sending drawing updates in batches to reduce the overhead.   Have you profiled the code to see what your resource consumption is?  That might give you insights into where your problem lies.

Comment: I am also tracking the users mouse movement and displaying the movement to other connected users. There is no lag during mouse movement.
I am facing lag only when I draw something on canvas

Comment: Without posting a reproducible code snippet it's very hard to understand what is happening in your application or provide any help.  Please update your question with a working code snippet.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the snippets